# How to get a process ID automaticly with command prompt

Tags: pid, command

I´d want to know how to get a PID of a process with a single command in command prompt.
I tried it with findstr, but I´m (apparently) not so smart to figure it out. You cannot use tasklist, because you ´ill need to find PID of cmd.exe your self. So, what´s the command to do
this searching automatic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't tell us about your OS, but i can see 2 ways for this :

E.g : to find PID for process `cmd.exe` :

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq cmd.exe" /FO LIST | findstr "PID:"

PID:                 8748
```

Powershell :

```
Get-Process cmd | select-object id

   Id
   --
 8748
```